# Finding the correct family of equations for the given equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

In my calculus book, (not for homework, I was just looking around), I was given the following equality and was told to find all valid functions that fit it.

Find all families of functions that satisfy the following equality:
$$\bigg(\int f(t)dt\bigg)\bigg(\int {1\over f(t)}dt\bigg)=-1$$

My two failed attempts to solve this yielded $f(x)=e^x+C$ and $f(x)=e^{-x}+C$ depending on my methods.

What families of functions satisfies this relationship?

Comment: Maybe begin by taking the derivative: $f(x)\int \dfrac{1}{f(t)}dt +\dfrac{1}{f(t)} \int f(t)dt=0$.

Comment: For the particular case in which the constant is $0$ you have an example with the family $f_a(x)=ae^x$.